# Why Type zzz is not assignable to type (zzz & NgIterable<xxx>) | undefined | null

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

In Angular 9 why do I get this message:
Type Items is not assignable to type (Items & NgIterable) | undefined | null

The model is correct. I get no error on the data.
The code works but still I get this typescript warning.

the model of myData looks like this:

```
interface Item {
  url: string;
  label: string;
}

export interface Items {
  [key:number]: Item ;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let card of myData"><!-- here I get the warning -->
some content
</ng-container>
```

ADDED: I forgot to add the example data to make this clearer.
It is an array like this:

```
[
    {
      url: 'todo',
      label: 'Rekeningnummer'
    },
    {
      url: 'todo',
      label: 'Postadres'
    }]
```

Comment: below the ng-container, add this: <div>{{myData | json}}</div>.  This should tell you what that data actually looks like to the template.  My bet is that myData is not an array or other iterable data type.

Comment: I forgot to add the example data to make this clearer. It is an array: `[
    {
      url: 'todo',
      label: 'Rekeningnummer'
    },
    {
      url: 'todo',
      label: 'Postadres'
    }] `

Comment: How did you define myData in you component.ts?

Comment: myData: Items = DATAMOCK and DATAMOCK is defined as type "Items"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using type Item[] instead of Items.

```
myData: Item[] = [...]
```

I read that Indexes of the form [key: string]: T can be considered as being always optional. So it seems that I cannot use ? to make the array possibly empty.

```
export interface Items {
  [key:number]?: Item ;
}
```